# Using userscript GM_functions inside the page context

Tags: greasemonkey, userscripts, ninjakit

I want to "re-link" everything in a specific page through a XMLHTTPRequest to a local network domain. That would lead me to GM_xmlhttpRequest in GreaseMonkey/NinjaKit except that I want to run it *when* the link is clicked, not when the userscript actually runs...

So I have something like:

```
links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    oldhref = links[i].getAttribute('href');
    links[i].setAttribute('href', 'javascript:loadLink(' + oldhref + ')');
}
```

I understand I can either use unsafeWindow or add a *script* element to *document* to inject *loadLink* function.
But how can I use *GM_xmlhttpRequest* in *loadLink*?

I've looked at [0.7.20080121.0 Compatibility](http://wiki.greasespot.net/0.7.20080121.0_compatibility) page but I'm not sure if that is for what I need...

I've also considered adding an *iframe* to the page and the modified links would load inside the *iframe* (triggering the userscript again), but I'd prefer a cleaner solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost never need to use GM functions inside the page context, and from the code posted so far, you don't need `unsafeWindow` in this case either.

Also, it is not necessary to rewrite the `href` for what is posted so far.

Something like this will accomplish what you want:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName ('a');

for (var J = 0, len = links.length;  J < len;  ++J) {
    links[J].addEventListener ("click", myLoadLink,   false);
}

function myLoadLink (zEvent) {
    zEvent.preventDefault();
    zEvent.stopPropagation();

    var targetHref = zEvent.currentTarget.getAttribute ('href');

    GM_xmlhttpRequest ( {
        //wtv
    } );

    return false;
}
```

Or with jQuery:

```
$("a").click (myLoadLink);

function myLoadLink () {

    var targetHref = $(this).attr ('href');

    GM_xmlhttpRequest ( {
        //wtv
    } );

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I managed to get that GreaseMonkey official workaround working (dunno what I did wrong the first time) with:

```
unsafeWindow.loadLink = function(href) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        GM_xmlhttpRequest({
            //wtv
        });
    },0);
}
```

But I'd still prefer a solution without using *unsafeWindow* if there is one... (especially since this one feels so *wrong*...)